# how to commit on master branch using last dev branch commit?

Tags: git

there is two branch, I work on dev branch, and I want to let the last commmit of dev branch to be the first commit of master branch.

how to make a commit of current working directory to another branch, when current working directory is clean. I don't want to use git merge, because it will add previous git log of current branch to another branch

Comment: What's your question exactly? The stash stores (multiple) changes that can be re-applied at any time (though they may conflict in the future). It's intended to reset a dirty state quickly (to do other work or checkout another branch without having to commit or losing data). A commit marks a change in your repository and will be part of its history. The stash only exists in the local git repo.

Comment: Yes it is *like* a commit. But only ever on your local repo and it does not update any branches. It also stores the reference in the stash stack

Comment: A stash **is** a commit. Read the [DISCUSSION](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_discussion) section on the [documentation page of `git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Answer (score 1):

I think all the stuff in your question about `stash` is fluff. If I understand your question correctly:

> how to make a commit of current working directory to another branch, when current working directory is clean. I don't want to use git merge, because it will add previous git log of current branch to another branch

You want to take the current state of files in one branch and apply them to another without using merge.

If that's all you want to do, then you can actually use [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203) (weird, huh?)

Checkout the branch you want to apply the changes to (we'll call it `target_branch`)

```
> git checkout target_branch
```

Then use this command:

```
> git checkout source_branch -- <glob pattern>
```

Where `<glob pattern>` is something like `path/to/file` or just `.` if you want to pull everything. (Note that the directory you are currently in is significant.)

Rather than checking out the `source_branch`, you'll actually just be pulling the specified files from that branch into your `target_branch`. Note that the history of those files will not be applied... only the actual contents, as if you had manually copy/pasted them.

Comment: when I look up similar question in stackoverflow, I find thr answer is using git stash. I thought this may also use git stash:

Answer (score 1):

Both your understandings of "stash" are actually correct.

From the user's perspective, `git stash` is simply here to store your current changes, then enable yourself to move through your history, perform some command, etc. then let you easily come back where you were and resume your work.

Also, since you may perform some additionnal changes (especially when you forget you're actually stashing something), `git stash` acts like a stack, stashing your current changes on top of the previous ones, which enables you to successively go back to the previous state until you reach back the initial one. `git stash list` will let you know where you are.

From a **technical** point of view, now, git doesn't need additional stuff at all to fulfill this task. It's already provided with everything it needs. In fact, when you stash something, git will build a `commit` object exactly the way it would if you were really adding/commiting your files. This commit object admits as a parent the revision you're currently working on and is referenced in a file stored in `.git/refs/stash`, just like the regular branches.

In that way, the stash stack is managed just like a ordinary branch, that would have forked from the point you're were working at, and can be handled that way if needed. The only thing that changes is at user interface's level. Popping the top of the stack is just a matter of checking out the last revision, then resetting to the previous one, except that this is done automaticaly.

Moreover, since once the place is clean, you're allowed to move everywhere in the history of your repository (which includes the possibility of jumping from a branch to another), stash commit objets actually contains two parents : the first one is the reference of the previous one, the second one is the revision you're are on when you call `git stash`.

This way of doing is what is actually done when one actually **merges** two branches. When displayed inside a graphical interface such as `gitk`, this shows the whole stash stack as a vertical lineage having branches that point on every revision you were when you stashed something.

This totally makes sense once we know it, but it can be kinda puzzling before indeed.

> **update** stash is thought to be the commit, which store the state of working directory, and does it mean stash to reapply changes by compare the dirty state of working directory to previous clean state of working directory?

The answer is "yes". If git detects some another changes when you want to pop the stashed ones, the operation will abort and git will warn you about the fact that this will clobber your last changes.

You may force it (with `-f`) if this is what you want, or you can stash it on top the existing. And if you fall back in a situation where the previous changes need to be restored *before* the last one, you can use `git stash apply` to re-apply any stage of your stash lineage without removing it from stack.